# ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient.Render to reportviewer control

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting

Is there a way to get the ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient.Render method to render the report to a reportviewer control. I have found examples to render to PDF, but not to the report viewer control.

Here is an example to render to pdf
[ReportExecutionService.Render Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx)

If I can render to html, that is fine as well. I am busy to create a report viewer for my MVC App, that i can just point to the reporting service web service then all the reports will be available as part of my application.

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code:
http://ikbalouch.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/calling-sql2008-reporting-server-webservice-programmaticall/

or try below:

http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/26/executing-reporting-services-web-service-from-asp-net-mvc-using-wcf-add-service-reference.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For what it know, the ReportViewer control just renders their own report format, so you may either just send the report format to the ReportViewer control or simply render the report to HTML4 and use a WebBrowser control or something similar.